# AutoMapper - how to return values from foreign key?

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework, automapper

How i can resolve problem, with map values from other table by foregin key? I have 2 tables (Client, Repair).

```
public class Repair
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Warranty { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Client))]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }
}

public class RepairReadDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Warranty { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int ClientId { get; set; }
}
```

Response for now looks like that:
[
{
"id": 1,
"warranty": "3",
"description": "aaaa",
"clientId": 1,
}
]

It's possible to get values by foregin key from other table? For example i expect output like this:

```
[
    {
        "id": 1,
        "warranty": "3",
        "description": "aaaa",
        "client":{"ClientId": 1, "Name": Example, "Surname": Example, "Phone": 1234567
    }
]
```

Comment: Yes, It is possible. But you haven't mention where do you have issue? Is it in AutoMapper or in EntityFramework?

Comment: The problem is i think with automapper, my map looks like that :            CreateMap<Repair, RepairReadDto>();

I need do something more?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think having something like follows would help you. Basically, Auto Mapper is able to map Child Objects too, but it should be defined and Classes should be created accordingly.

```
public class Repair
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Warranty { get; set; }

    [Required]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [ForeignKey(nameof(Client))]
    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    public virtual Client Client { get; set; }
}

public class RepairReadDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }

    public string Warranty { get; set; }

    public string Description { get; set; }

    public int ClientId { get; set; }

    public ClientDto Client { get; set; }
}

public class Client
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}

public class ClientDto
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

On AutoMapper

```
CreateMap<Repair, RepairReadDto>()..ReverseMap();
CreateMap<Client, ClientDto>()..ReverseMap();
```

Answer (score 0):

Okey, right now if im using two different tables(Client,Repair) i need to import repository on each of them and fill "Client" from Repair in controller.

```
public ActionResault<IEnumerable<RepairReadDto>> GetRepairList()
{
     var repairList = _repairRepo.GetProductList().Tolist();
     foreach(var repair from repairList)
     {
        repair.Client = _mapper.Map<ClientReadDto>(_clientRepo.GetClientById(repair.ClientId))
     }
     
     return Ok(repairList);
}
```

Is there any other convention to do that?